# Mapping wrapped auto-generated primary key in Hibernate xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to map the following object to the database table with Hibernate 5.0.

```
class Ticket {

  private TicketId ticketId;
  private String description;

  private Ticket() {}
  private Ticket(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
  public TicketId ticketId() { return ticketId; }
  public String description() { return description; }
  // equals and hashCode
}
```

where `TicketId` is a quite simple wrapped primary key that needs to be auto-generated in the database:

```
class TicketId implements Serializable {

  private Long id;

  private TicketId() {}
  public Long id() { return id; }
  // equals and hashCode
}
```

The MySQL database table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `TICKETS` (
  `ID` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I've read [the article by Vlad Michalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), but I want to use xml and I came up with the following mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field" default-cascade="all"
  xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">
  <class name="some.package.Ticket" table="TICKETS" lazy="true">
    <composite-id name="ticketId">
      <key-property name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <sql-insert>INSERT INTO TICKETS (DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?)</sql-insert>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, the ORM code fails when I try to persist new `Ticket`.
The following code produces `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class some.package.Ticket`

```
try (final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
  final Ticket ticket = new Ticket("description");
  session.save(ticket);
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?